# Constructing a closed surface given the equation of an open surface

Tags: surfaces, surface-integrals, divergence-operator

As an example, in order to apply the Gauss's theorem, one must have a closed surface. Hence, if one is given the equation of an open surface S: $$1-z=x^2 + y^2 , 0\le z \le1$$ 
and if we want to calculate, using Gauss's theorem $$\int_S \bar F\cdot d\bar S$$ then we will need to construct a closed surface including the surface S given above. I realise that this is a circle on the xy plane and I am able to solve this problem.

However, my question is, more generally, are there any standard procedures or method which allows one to construct a closed surface from an arbitrary equation of an open surface, **without the need to first visualise the surface given**? An example of such a method in the answer will be much appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your surface is already closed. (Solve for $z$)

Comment: @coffeemath I don't think $1-z = x^2 + y^2$ is actually a closed surface?

Comment: It gives $z=f(x,y)=1-x^2-y^2.$ That's continuous so (1) with no restriction on $z$ it's closed (inverse image of the reals) and (2) with your restriction $0 \le z \le 1$ it's also closed (inverse image of a closed set).